# Pass parameters in constructor instead of setting propeties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oop, constructor

I have used `constructor` only for Dependency Injection in MVC and created all my application or entity objects with out a construction like below

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public Type PropName{get;set;}
}
```

However I see many are using constructor for some purpose. I know we can use constructor to initialize something. But `what are the scenarios should I consider to create a constructor like below?` with readonly fields and setting them

```
public class Licence
{
    private readonly Instant expiry;
    private readonly IClock clock;

    public Licence(Instant expiry, IClock clock)
    {
        this.expiry=expiry;
        this.clock=clock;
    }

    //some methods & prop goes here
}
```

I have mostly seen this kind of code in Frameworks like MVC and some high level Application Frameworks designed by Architects.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you'd pass in parameters in a constructor when you don't want those values to be changed after the object is instantiated; this can apply to a variety of situations, including Dependency Injection.  A common case for this is custom `Exception` classes, where you want to pass on additional information that can't be modified:

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public string MyField { get; private set; }

    public MyException(string myField)
    {
        this.MyField = myField;
    }
}
```

For Dependency Injection, consider providing a log provider implementation to your class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public ILogger Logger { get; private set; }

    public MyClass(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.Logger = logger;
    }
}
```

In both of these cases, you don't want the properties to change once you create them because they would change the fundamental meaning or behavior of the instance.

Comment: What about defining them as `readonly` and setting it in constructor?

Comment: That's fine if you're fine with exposing members directly through the class, but it doesn't work in all situations.  For example, in several cases if you want to bind to that value, it has to be done as a property and not a member (i.e. in `WPF`, binding grids to a list of your class properties).

Answer (score 2):

I only use constructors in classes where I use dependency injection or when I want to set data which I don't want to change anymore. For example, a MVC controller:

```
private readonly IProductService _productService;
private readonly IShoppingCartService _shoppingCartService;

public ProductController(IProductService productService,
                         IShoppingCartService shoppingCartService)
{
    _productService = productService;
    _shoppingCartService = shoppingCartService;
}
```

For my domain models, I *don't* create constructors to fill my public properties. That would result in a constructor like this:

```
public Order(string orderReference,
             string userEmail,
             string paymentIssuer,
             bool? isProcessed,
             ICollection<OrderDetail> orderDetails)
{
    OrderReference = orderReference;
    UserEmail = userEmail;
    PaymentIssuer = paymentIssuer;
    IsProcessed = isProcessed;
    OrderDetails = orderDetails;
}
```

We can call this constructor this way:

```
new Order("test", "john@doe.com", "test", true, null);
```

Which makes it completely unclear that the arguments mean, I prefer the [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx). Which looks like this:

```
new Order
    {
        OrderReference = "test",
        UserEmail = "john@doe.com",
        PaymentIssuer = "test",
        IsProcessed = true
    };
```

However, I *do* sometimes create a parameterless constructor for my domain models where I set some default data:

```
public Order()
{
    UserId = Guid.NewGuid();
    OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>();
}
```